# Clean architecture with golang - Store Error handling

Tags: go, error-handling, clean-architecture

I'm currently trying to implement the [Clean architecture pattern](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) in Golang.

In my store/repository I have a function to load an entity from the database. In my case a User entity. In my authentication use-case I have a login function that should load the User entity from the store/repository and check the password.

The repository throws an (in my case gorm) error if the user is not found, which is totally okay. However, if the User entity is not found I want to respond with something like "Invalid Params" and not with a 500 Error (Internal Server Error), which is usually thrown if an error occurs in my repository. This means I have to check the error in my controller and send a response respectively.

It would work, but I would have to import the gorm exceptions in my controller, which is definitely an anti pattern, as my controller layer should not know anything about my repository layer. If I wanted to change my repository I would have to change my error handling in my controller too...

Is there a clean solution for this?

One thing I thought about was to wrap the gorm errors around my own ones, but I cannot wrap every gorm error which I would have to do since my function to load an User in my repository may be used by other Use-Cases and not only the login one. Currently I'm not doing any testing, but if I want to mock my store I have to wrap every database error, haven't I?

Help is appreciated, have a great day!

Comment: You only need to wrap those errors that the caller needs to handle in some particular way (like your not found error). For other error types where the app makes no distinction, there's no need to wrap it.

Comment: @Adrian Yeah that's true, I did not quite think about that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func (s *UserManager) Login(form users.LoginForm) (string, error) {

    user, err := s.Repository.FindByEmail(form.Email)
    if err != nil || user == nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return "", errors.New(utils.UserRecordNotFound) -> In this line I am returning my own error message to my controller
    }

    is_match, err := argon2.ComparePassword(form.Password, user.PasswordHash)
    if err != nil || !is_match {
        return "", errors.New(utils.UserNameOrPasswordIncorrect)
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return token, nil
    }
```

In this way you will hide your internal error messages from users.